# org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity

Tags: java, hibernate

It work in another example but this one it not. I'm copy code and edit line from line but it keep showing the error. I dont know what wrong with the QLKH_DTO class. I'm using netbean 15 and hibernate 6.

`The entity class`

```
package DTO;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "customers", catalog = "market")

public class QLKH_DTO implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Integer CustomerID;
    private String Password;
    private String Fullname; 
    private String Address;
    private String City;
    
    public QLKH_DTO(){}
     public QLKH_DTO(String Password,String Fullname, String Address, String City) {
        this.Password = Password;
        this.Fullname = Fullname;
        this.Address = Address;
        this.City = City;
    }
     
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    
    @Column(name = "CustomerID")
    public Integer getCustomerID() {
        return CustomerID;
    }

    public void setCustomerID(Integer CustomerID) {
        this.CustomerID = CustomerID;
    }
    @Column(name = "Password")
    public String getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String PassWord) {
        this.Password = PassWord;
    }
    @Column(name = "Fullname")
    public String getFullname() {
        return Fullname;
    }

    public void setFullname(String FullName) {
        this.Fullname = FullName;
    }
    @Column(name = "Address", length = 20)
    public String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String Address) {
        this.Address = Address;
    }
    @Column(name = "City", length = 20)
    public String getCity() {
        return City;
    }

    public void setCity(String City) {
        this.City = City;
    }
   
}
```

`The test class`

```
package GUI.QLKH;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
 
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
 
import DTO.QLKH_DTO;
import utils.HibernateUtil;
 
public class QLKH {
    private static SessionFactory factory;
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // get session factory
        factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
 
        // create manageEmployee object
        QLKH Customer = new QLKH();
 
        
        System.out.println("List down all the customers:");
        Customer.listCustomers();
    }

    public void listCustomers() {
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        try {
            List customers = session.createQuery("FROM customers").list();
            for (Iterator iterator = customers.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                QLKH_DTO customer = (QLKH_DTO) iterator.next();
                System.out.print("ID " + customer.getCustomerID());
                System.out.print("Password " + customer.getPassword());
                System.out.print("Fullname " + customer.getFullname());
                System.out.println("Address " + customer.getAddress());
                System.out.println("City " + customer.getCity());
            }
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

`The HibernateUtill Class`

```
package utils;
 
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
 
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
    public static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
            serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .configure()
                    .build();
            Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry)                                     
                        .getMetadataBuilder().build();
            return metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

`The hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
   
      <property name = "hibernate.dialect">
         org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
      </property>
   
      <property name = "hibernate.connection.driver_class">
         com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      </property>

      <!-- Assume students is the database name -->
   
      <property name = "hibernate.connection.url">
          jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/market
      </property>
   
      <property name = "hibernate.connection.username">
         root
      </property>
   
      <property name = "hibernate.connection.password">
         
      </property>
    <mapping class="DTO.QLKH_DTO" />
   </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

`The sql`

```
CREATE TABLE `Customers` (
  `CustomerID` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Password` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Fullname` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `City` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `Customers`
--

INSERT INTO `Customers` (`CustomerID`, `Password`, `Fullname`, `Address`, `City`) VALUES
(1, 'Abcd1234', 'John Smith', '30 Broadway', 'London'),
(2, 'Abcd1234', 'Jonny English', '99 River View', 'Reading'),
(3, 'Abcd1234', 'Elizabeth', '23 Buckinghamshire', 'York'),
(4, 'Abcd1234', 'Beatrix', '66 Royal Crescent', 'Bath');
```

`The Error log`

```
Nov 21, 2022 9:27:01 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.5.Final
Nov 21, 2022 9:27:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using built-in connection pool (not intended for production use)
Nov 21, 2022 9:27:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: Loaded JDBC driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Nov 21, 2022 9:27:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001012: Connecting with JDBC URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/market]
Nov 21, 2022 9:27:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=root}
Nov 21, 2022 9:27:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Nov 21, 2022 9:27:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH10001115: Connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Nov 21, 2022 9:27:09 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl logSelectedDialect
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Nov 21, 2022 9:27:13 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
List down all the customers:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity 'customers'
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:761)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:663)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:127)
    at GUI.QLKH.QLKH.listCustomers(QLKH.java:32)
    at GUI.QLKH.QLKH.main(QLKH.java:27)
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity 'customers'
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitRootEntity(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1628)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitRootEntity(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$RootEntityContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1873)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitEntityWithJoins(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1548)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitFromClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1539)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuery(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:833)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:629)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$QuerySpecExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1218)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:623)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$SimpleQueryGroupContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1131)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSelectStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:399)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.buildSemanticModel(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.translate(StandardHqlTranslator.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.lambda$createQuery$2(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:748)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.createHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.resolveHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:745)
    ... 4 more
Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:982)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:929)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:457)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
```

It look like the problem mostly in the entity class but i don't know where.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `session.createQuery("FROM customers")` your entity is not called `customers` it is called `QLKH_DTO`

Comment: The QLKH_DTO mapping to "customers" in database

Comment: Hibernate doesn't care about what its called in the database. It cares about your code

Comment: oh thanks it work,such a dump question

Comment: For those who google the error message: In my case, entity class wasn't added to session factory, like`.addAnnotatedClass(User.class)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

XtremeBauumer answered it in the comments:

> session.createQuery("FROM customers") your entity is not called customers it is called QLKH_DTO

> Hibernate doesn't care about what its called in the database. It cares about your code

Comment: change session.createQuery("FROM customers")  to session.createQuery("FROM QLKH_DTO") as the entity name is QLKH_DTO

Answer (score 1):

The main pitfall is use your entity name in your query, not the database name - often simply a matter of capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error - just because of small mistake

```
@Entity(name = "result")
public class Result { .... }
```

My query was -

```
SELECT r FROM Result - changed Result to result as mentioned in entity name.
```